# Screen rotation even though its disabled in code

Tags: java, android

I'm having this problem for a few weeks now and couldn't find anything in web. At the moment I'm coding an android App and I disabled the screen rotation via code:

```
setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

And in xml:

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

But the screen is still rotation sometimes for a short time (~1s and then back).
Is there any other opportunity how I can fix that? I thought about disabling the system setting for screen rotation via code (On this devices is only my App running) but even for that I couldn't find any solutions.

Comment: Is this something that happens on several devices/emulators, or only to one of these?

Comment: @DanielBeleza Its happening on all of them. The devices are Zebra TC71. I'm also able to recreate this problem nearly everytime. When I start the App and this device is located on a table or so, the screen is suddenly rotating.